# @IBDesignables - "the agent crashed" but app still works (most of the time)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a pretty strange problem with a project. XCode gives me red errors all the time and says that my IBDesignables have a problem. But the error message differs every time and it's always another view controller affected. I have no idea how to find the cause of the problem. It seems to happen randomly with all IBDesignables I created.

The app does still work. Although, sometimes it doesn't render some views correctly (I have views with a custom drawn mask). It happens rarely, but it does happen.

These are errors I get:

> "Failed to update the auto layout status: The agent crashed"
>
> "Failed to render and update the auto layout status for {randomly
>   chosen VC name}: The agent crashed"

The latter disappears as soon as I click on it. And sometimes, when I'm inside my storyboard, all of the errors go away. When I open any other file, I get multiple red errors (sometimes like 3, sometimes 6 or more).

I checked the crash logs. Every single one of them says:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I'm not sure what this means.

I tried cleaning the project and restarting XCode.
Also, I implemented all of the `init` methods.

This following code is a `class` that (almost) always is part of the errors I get. Also, it's the custom drawn view that sometimes doesn't render correctly:

```
import UIKit

struct TriangleViewLabelDefault {
    static let triangleWidth: CGFloat = 20
    static let triangleHeight: CGFloat = 10
}

@IBDesignable
class TriangleView: UIView {
    let DEFAULT_TRIANGLE_WIDTH: CGFloat = 30
    let DEFAULT_TRIAGNLE_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 20


    struct Triangle {
        static var width: CGFloat = TriangleViewLabelDefault.triangleWidth
        static var height: CGFloat = TriangleViewLabelDefault.triangleHeight
        static var midXPosition: CGFloat = 0
    }

    @IBInspectable var triangleWidth: CGFloat = TriangleViewLabelDefault.triangleWidth {
        didSet {
            Triangle.width = triangleWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var triangleHeight: CGFloat = TriangleViewLabelDefault.triangleHeight {
        didSet {
            Triangle.height = triangleHeight
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var relativePosition: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var triangleMidXOffset: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var decoration: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var lines: Int = 20 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        calcTriangleMidXPosition()
        addLines()
        if decoration {
            addDecoration()
        }

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds

        let maskPath = UIBezierPath()
        maskPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: Triangle.height))
        /* Triangle */
        maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: Triangle.midXPosition - Triangle.width, y: Triangle.height))
        maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: Triangle.midXPosition, y: 0))
        maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: Triangle.midXPosition + Triangle.width, y: Triangle.height))
        /* */
        maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width, y: Triangle.height))
        maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width, y: bounds.size.height))
        maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.size.height))
        maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: Triangle.height))

        maskPath.close()

        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }

    /// Evaluates the properties set in storyboard. This methods calculates the x-center of the triangle
    private func calcTriangleMidXPosition() {
        if relativePosition {
            Triangle.midXPosition = bounds.size.width / 2 + triangleMidXOffset * bounds.size.width / 2
        } else {
            Triangle.midXPosition = bounds.size.width / 2 + triangleMidXOffset
        }
    }

    private func addDecoration() {
        if let superview = superview {

            let topLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.minY + Triangle.height - 2, width: bounds.size.width, height: 1))
            let bottomLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.minY + Triangle.height - 4, width: bounds.size.width, height: 1))

            topLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            topLine.alpha = 0.5
            bottomLine.alpha = 0.2

            superview.insertSubview(topLine, belowSubview: self)
            superview.insertSubview(bottomLine, belowSubview: self)
        }
    }

    private func addLines() {

        guard lines > 0 else {
            return
        }

        let paddingLeft: Int = 20
        let lineLength: Int = 25

        let linesLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        linesLayer.frame = bounds

        let padding: CGFloat = 20

        let minY = Triangle.height + padding
        let maxY = bounds.height - padding
        let yArea = maxY - minY



        for x in 0...lines {
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.lineWidth = 3.0

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(paddingLeft), y: minY + CGFloat(x) * yArea / CGFloat(lines)))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(paddingLeft) + CGFloat(lineLength), y: minY + CGFloat(x) * yArea / CGFloat(lines)))

            UIColor(red: 200.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 200.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).setStroke()
            path.stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you guys for any help!

Comment: I have simliar problem today, and I have tried to `debug` the class, and found that the crashed is due to the property not initialise probably, so you may need to debug and see which statement make it crash.

Comment: You mean setting a break point and stepping through the execution? I tried that, it didn't crash, unfortunately. I tried multiple times

Comment: no, goto `identify inspector`, and you will see the `Designable` tag at the top, and there is a small `debug` button on the right. Click the `debug` button, you can see which statement make you crash

Comment: I didn't find it in the identity inspector, but I used "Editor -> debug selected Views". I skipped through it and it indeed crashed. I will take a look into this now. Maybe that's what caused my problem. Thanks, so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code make you crash, you should found a `debug` button in the `identify inspector` as screenshot below. After you click the debug button, you can found out which statement make you crash.

[image]

Comment: The thing is: The view that crashes (while debugging) doesn't have a `debug` button. Does this mean it's not causing the problem? I checked every single `IBDesignable` in m storyboard, I can't find any debug button. It's strange. But I still have to figure the crash out, that I just found

Comment: Okay, I'm pretty sure I found the problem. This line (inside a `layoutSubviews` method) is causing the problem: `superview!.addSubview(maxFillLabel)`. I believe, `superview` is nil, that's why it crashes. This would fit into the crash log description. Now I have to fix that. Thanks for the tip with debugging. Didn't know that until now :)

Comment: so what is your `designable` status for your view? `crash`? the debug button only exist when the status is equal to crash.

Comment: No, the status is `up to date`, even though it crashes when I try to debug it

Comment: Now I fixed the crash, all errors are gone. But now I get `Build failed` and a `Show` button next to it. But nothing happens when I click on it. Also, the view is just white without any content. But when I start the app, it's working

Answer (score 11):

Every time this "Agent crashed" issue occures, a crash log is created. You can find all of them here:

```
~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
```

named IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch_*.crash

Just go into Finder (Go->Go to folder), copy the path and substitute  with your username.

Probably you'll have too many of crash logs there, you can delete them all, clean your project, build again and check the folder.

Comment: Thanks, but I already found them :). In my question, I quoted the error of the crash log. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Usually crash log specifies the exact line number where the crash happened, like this: AppDelegate.swift:17. Can you see it there?

Comment: No, at least I couldn't find a line number

Comment: Can you please provide the stack trace from any crash log?

Comment: Not sure, what part of the crash log that is :D But I did find the cause (see answer above)

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem when creating a checkbox button, with 2 UIImage defined, for checked and unchecked.
Code did work well, but Agent crashed for IBDesignable (IBInspectable was OK)

I noticed several causes :
 UIImages must not be created inside the class
I had to declare outside, with a property to hold the selected image, and initialise in init(coder):

```
import UIKit
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked")!// as UIImage
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked")!// as UIImage

@IBDesignable class CheckBox: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable public var image: UIImage?
```

I had to remove the setImage in computed property

```
@IBInspectable public var isChecked: Bool = false { // this caused a crash
   didSet{
      if isChecked == true {
          self.setImage(checkedImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
      } else {
          self.setImage(uncheckedImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
      }
   }
}
```

to just keep

```
@IBInspectable public var isChecked: Bool = false
```

Finally added a draw func

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    image?.draw(in: rect)
}
```

If that may help others.